# How to enable resizeable column for rich faces extendedDatatable?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

For `extendedDataTable` in rich faces how we can resize the column width using mouse pointer.

Does any body know about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to resize the column width using mouse pointer then in this situation **rich:scrollableDataTable** is a best i thing..

see demo on this link

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/scrollableDataTable.jsf;jsessionid=9DED0BD699C3630FE0C6314C69DF709B?c=scrollableDataTable&tab=usage

Comment: but i dont want rich:scrollableDataTable for  extendedDataTable only i want how can i achieve this